# Opengl triangle not drawn

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, vbo

I'm trying to draw a simple triangle on the screen. The window gets properly set up and everything seems okay to the point, where I'm trying to actually draw stuff. I have the following code, but it doesn't work for some reason.

`default_shader_program` is program linking shaders shown after the function code

```cpp
void window::run(void(*update)(), void(*draw)()) {
    while (glfwWindowShouldClose(wnd) == 0)
    {

        update();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        draw();
        GLuint vb;
        GLfloat data[12]{
            1.f, 1.f, 0.f,
            1.f, -1.f, 0.f,
            -1.f, 0.f, 0.f
        };


        glGenBuffers(1, &vb);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GLuint va;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &va);
        glBindVertexArray(va);

        glUseProgram(default_shader_program);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(wnd);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(wnd);
}
```

Shaders:
vertexshader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location=0) in vec3 vertexPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1);
}
```

fragmentshader:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;

void main() {
    color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Yes, I know, that I am buffering data and doing other stuff in while loop. I know, that it shouldn't be done like that, but the actual problem occured somewhere else and I wanted to see if code will work properly directly inside the loop.

Comment: Why does you data array have 12 elements? I don't think that this is an problem, but its just odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains 9 elements instead of 12, but that doesn't cause the issue.

The 2nd argument of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) is the buffer size in bytes. Hence the size of the buffer is `9*sizeof(GLfloat)` rather than 12:

<s>`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`</s>

```cpp
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked... Almost. I see a white triangle instead of red, as it is specified in the shader. Why is that?

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Most likely your shader is not loaded, compiled, linked or activated correctly, but that is another question.

Comment: Yes. Since the project is compiled as lib, the output is used seperately from the source files. The shader files were unaccessible from the code.